# How do I find the index of an integer array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code I'm writing, and it searches an array for user input. Once it's found, I want it to tell me which position (I think it's called the index) it was in, in the array.

Here's what I have for finding the array.

```
if (rooms.contains(input)){
            System.out.println("That teacher is in our database!");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, that teachner was not found in our database!");
    }
```

The

```
input
```

is the user input, from a Scanner.

I'm not sure how I can find the index of the number, once found.

I've tried:

```
            System.out.println(new int[(rooms).indexOf()]);
```

Sadly, that hasn't worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the type of `rooms`?

Comment: That is ***not*** an array. The fact that you're calling `.contains` on it shows it is some type of collection, probably a `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call indexOf() as the following:

```
rooms.indexOf(input);
```

Here is [the document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)).